# MonoMac / Xamarin.Mac binding simple dylib not working

Tags: mono, monomac, xamarin.mac

I'm trying to bind some native code for use in MonoMac / Xamarin.Mac, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I create a simple dylib to test with:

*nativelibrary.h*:

```
- (NSString *)echo:(NSString *)message;
```

I know that my library is fine, because I reference it and use it in an Objective-C / Cocoa application.

Next, I try to generate the initial binding file using parse.exe:

```
mono parse.exe [path...]/nativelibrary.h
```

**Problem #1**
No 'gen.cs' file is generated as per Miguel's [guide](https://github.com/mono/monomac/blob/master/BINDING-HOWTO)

**Problem #2**
Parse.exe does actually output something to the console, although it's missing my only method?

```
[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
interface nativelibrary {
}
```

Regardless, I go ahead and make my own gen.cs file, filling in the missing method manually:

*gen.cs*:

```
using MonoMac.Foundation;

namespace ManagedConsumer
{
    [BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
    interface Binding 
    {
        [Export ("echo:")]
        string Echo(string message);

        // I also tried like this:
        // NSString Echo(NSString message);
    }
}
```

Next, I try to create my binding DLL using bmac.exe:

```
mono bmac.exe -o="dynamiclibrary.dll" -d="MONOMAC" -r="System.Drawing" -v [path].../gen.cs
```

This spits out a .dll which I reference in my MonoMac project.

Finally, I add the .dylib itself to my MonoMac project, and specify the 'content' build action. I verify that the .dylib is copied to the 'Resources' directory of my bundle.

I can instantiate an instance of my binding object no problem:

```
Binding b = new Binding();
Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
```

**Problem 3** However, trying to call my method:

```
Binding b = new Binding();
var result = b.Echo((NSString)"Hello, world");
```

results in an unmanaged crash:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000000bf74bffc
```

I have seen in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230031/coreplot-monomac-bindings-crashing), that we need to force the .dylib to load. So I try to insert this line into my *main.cs*, before *Application.Init()* is called:

```
Dlfcn.dlopen ("nativelibrary.dylib", 0);
```

But I get the same crash. Since the call to *dlopen* returns 0 rather than a valid pointer, I assume that the issue is in loading my dynamic library. I also tried to use the attribute:

```
[assembly:MonoMac.RequiredFramework("nativelibrary.dylib")]
```

But that only gets me:

```
System.Exception: Unable to load required framework: 'nativelibrary.dylib'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After **a lot** of trial and error, I was able to make this work. Two changes:

In my homebrew *gen.cs* file, the interface name needed to match the name of my native class, i.e.

*nativelibrary.h*

```
@interface nativelibrary : NSObject

- (NSString *)echo:(NSString *)message;
```

*gen.cs*

using MonoMac.Foundation;

```
namespace ManagedConsumer
{
    [BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
    interface nativelibrary 
    {
        [Export ("echo:")]
        string Echo(string message);
    }
}
```

Secondly, it seems there was something about my native library itself that means it couldn't be opened with *dlopen*. I think the problem is that the XCode 'library' project defaults to x64, and it appears only x86 will work.

I compiled it from the command line instead, like so:

```
gcc -arch i386 -framework Cocoa -o nativelibrary.o  -c [path...]/nativelibrary.m
```

Then built my library:

```
libtool -dynamic -flat_namespace -lSystem -undefined suppress -macosx_version_min 10.6 -install_name $CURRENT_DIR/nativelibrary.dylib -o nativelibrary.dylib nativelibrary.o
```

And it now works.