# Call Objective C code from .NET / Mono(Mac)

Tags: mono, monomac

I'm porting a .NET-based test automation framework to Mac OS X.
I have significant .NET experience, however, I'm totally a rookie in the Mac world.

I need to call Objective C code from .NET / Mono. I started with the "[MonoMac - Binding Objective-C Types](http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMac/Documentation/Binding_New_Objective-C_Types)" tutorial.

- I created an API definition file. I couldn't compile it, because the type "BaseTypeAttribute" couldn't be found. Later I found that this is not a problem, because the btouch tool will compile it (basetypeattribute-not-found-in-a-binding-project).
- Since I'm developing for OS X (not iOS), I was not using btouch, I was going to use the bmac tool. Findig that wasn't trivial, but I managed to compile&found it [based on this article](http://marc.info/?l=mono-osx&m=134643291122150&w=2). Good.
- I was not able to compile my binding file, because the bmac said "Type or namespace 'Tasks' does not exists in namespace 'System.Threading'".
  Nevertheless, I specified an output folder for the generated .cs files, fixed the compile error (the Tasks wasn't really needed, the error was caused by an unnecessary using that was generated).
- So I'm about at the point where I could have been if I followed the manual "Binding New Objective-C Types / Binding_Details" document.

The problem is that I still cannot use my Objective C library.
I can compile and run the C# code with MonoDevelop/Xamarin, but it fails with the message:

```
System.Exception: Could not create an native instance of the type 'My.Type': the native class hasn't been loaded.
It is possible to ignore this condition by setting MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false.
 at MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject.InitializeObject (Boolean alloced)
 at MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject..ctor (MonoMac.Foundation.NSObjectFlag x)
 at My.Type..ctor ()
```

I found an article (coreplot-monomac-bindings-crashing) that says the library must be manually loaded before using it, but I had no luck with it. "Dlfcn.dlopen" always return IntPtr.Zero.

- I'm tried to create my lib as "Cocoa Framework", "Cocoa Library" and "Bundle" in XCode. Which one should I use?
- Are there any low-level debugging possibilites in Mono(Mac)?
- Did anybody managed to do this? (calling objc from .net)

thanks in advance,
-g

Comment: You need `Dlfcn.dlopen` to return a valid handle. Check that you are copying the framework into your application bundle and loading it with the correct path. I assume this works with libraries - but I have only ever used Cocoa Frameworks. Finally, make sure your native code is compiled for 32 bit. If it's x64 only, it won't work (monomac is currently 32 bit only)

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15073178/monomac-xamarin-mac-binding-simple-dylib-not-working

Comment: @TheNextman: Thanks for your comment!
Is there a tool like the Fusion Loader Log Viewer, that can show me why the library loading fails? Maybe I put my framework to the wrong place (I'm trying to load it from the folder where the XCode put the build result). Maybe I should copy it under /Libraries or something?

Comment: As far as I know, no such tool exists. In terms of troubleshooting, verify you can use your library in a regular Cocoa app first, maybe? It will tend to give slightly better information in case loading fails and will let you validate the library is not a problem. Next, in monomac, you can check the path is fine by doing something like `File.Exists(...path)`. And then, like I say, make sure your library is compiled for 32 bit.

Comment: I would definitely be trying to include your library in your application bundle, rather than trying to load it from wherever xcode drops it